# NoReverseMatch with Redirect in Django

Tags: django

I am very new to Python and Django. I am trying to redirect to a second view function. Here is my url configuration:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('dept.pv.verif.views',
    (r'^apps/dept/pv/verif/$', 'index', {}, 'index'),
    (r'^apps/dept/pv/verif/display$', 'display', {}, 'display'),
    (r'^apps/dept/pv/verif/display/(?P<action>\w{1})/(?P<id>\w{8})/$', 'display', {}, 'display'),
    url(r'^apps/dept/pv/verif/display/(?P<action>\w{1})/(?P<id>\w{8})/$', 'display', name='display'),)
```

And here are my view functions:

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    visit_switch = request.GET.get('visit_switch')
    if not visit_switch:
        id_form = Enter_ID()
    else:
        id_form = Enter_ID(request.GET)
        if id_form.is_valid():
            return redirect('display', action='R', id='test')
    context['id_form'] = id_form
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'context':context})
```

and the second:

```
def display(request, action, id):
# ...
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

I'm getting a NoReverseMatch error. I don't understand why the redirect line is not matching up with one of my urls. I would appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression group:

```
(?P<id>\w{8})
```

Will only match something 8 characters long. If you're actually passing `id='test'`, that would be your problem.